# Meteor sound Design

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects, sfx, sound-effects-recording, film-sound-design

I'm doing the sound design for an animation movie. There are a couple of scenes with a meteor shower. 
Could someone suggest me ​​any trick of how to sound design or replicate the sound of a meteor entering in the atmosphere? and the collision with the ground.

Thanks

Comment: Whatever you do, please don't make it the usual anything-threatening-explosive-or-similar rumble without delay.

Comment: If you listen to the extensive video footage from the Russian meteor a couple of years back, you'll get a good idea of what it sounds like from the ground behind and to the side of the track.

Comment: (It's nice to actually have a Sound Design question on this site again ;-)  )

Answer (score 2):

I've always used things like jet engines and thunder from libraries and a mish mash of other odds and sods. Another trick I tried was to compress a sound until it distorts the converter, (you need to turn your speakers off for this) then send it to another channel and record it at a lower level. If you've ever played Titanfall you'll know the sound I mean. The idea is that a meteor would be so loud it would have square waves.

Comment: I love that overloading sound you talk about. Enhances the loudness perception beutifully. I've used a similar process to brutally enhance musical elements.